# "Permission denied (publickey)" error when ssh'ing to Amazon EC2 Debian AMI 05f3ef71

Tags: ssh, debian, amazon-ec2

I have launched a Debian system using AMI 05f3ef71 in Amazon EC2, but I have no lock connecting to it using SSH as suggested in ["Connecting to Your Linux/UNIX Instances Using SSH"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html). I tried several user names: ec2-user, root, debian... None of them worked. I always get a `Permission denied (publickey)` error message.

Using `ec2-get-console-output instance_id` as suggested doesn't work either, it requires option "-K". If I supply it, I get the error message `Required option '-C, --cert CERT' missing`, but I have no idea what to supply there.

Port 22 is opened on the affected instance.

Does anyone have an idea what I could try to log in to my instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The username of the  AMI "05f3ef71" is admin

Source: https://wiki.debian.org/Cloud/AmazonEC2Image/Wheezy